# JS es6 on click add class to another element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show a div when another button has been clicked.

Unfortunately the site i'm using doesn't use jquery but has babel.js installed.

This is the HTML of the button the user is clicking

```
<button id="ba-Calculate" class="button">Calculate</button>
```

And this is the HTML for the button I would like to display

```
<button class="js-find-a-mortgage button u-margin-top-small" style="display: none;">Find a mortgage</button>
```

I've added a style of display none to hide the element.

This is what i've come up with so far.

```
var el = document.querySelector('#ba-Calculate');

el.onclick = function() {
document.getElementsByClassName('js-find-a-mortgage').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Any suggestions or where to read up on how I can crack this would be great.

I appreciate the feedback, thank you.

Comment: Is there only a single element with the class `js-find-a-mortgage` on the page?

Comment: What's the actual question? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: @BrettGregson Yes, Only the one element with that class name

Comment: I'd like to point out that none of the code mentioned here is ES6.

Comment: If you're using `style.`* and anything that is not some complicated transform or matrix - you're most probably doing it the wrong-ish way. `Element.classList` is your friend to add, remove, toggle classes to any element, than inside CSS you define your styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. So, you need to fetch the first element (I believe you have only one element with that class in the DOM) and add the style.

Try using

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-find-a-mortgage')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var trigger = document.querySelector('#ba-calculate')
var el = document.querySelector('.js-find-a-mortgate')

trigger.addEventListener('click', function () {
  el.style.display = 'block'
})
```

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array like object

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an
>   array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
>   class names. When called on the document object, the complete document
>   is searched, including the root node. You may also call
>   getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements
>   which are descendants of the specified root element with the given
>   class names.

Using `querySelector` will grab the first instance of a node matching that class name. You can then use the code you already had.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class, I assume you need to use `classList` method `add`:

For example to add for your element class 'hidden':
`document.getElementsByClassName('js-find-a-mortgage')[0].classList.add('hidden');`

To see all classes use: `document.getElementsByClassName('js-find-a-mortgage')[0].classList`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp